# How to Hide keyBoard on return button itself in TextView in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

In my iPhone App I am using the control UItextView,
I want to hide the keyBoard on "return" Button itself, I am not using any toolBar,NavigationBar and I  don't want to import any other control like button on that View.

What shold I do to hide keyboard ?

Please Help and Suggest,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate and look for a line break:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)string
{
    if([string isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: In this code when we paste text with 2 paragraph then it will not paste data